# How to prove that Φ² (golden ratio squared) is an algebraic number?

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-number-theory, golden-ratio

The golden ratio Φ  is algebraic since it is a root of the polynomial $x^2 - x - 1$

But how would you write and prove that Φ² is also algebraic?

Comment: Algebraic numbers are closed under addition and multiplication. Or, if it's just about $\phi^2$, square both sides of $\phi^2-1=\phi\,$.

Comment: Because $\phi^2$ would be a root of $$(\sqrt x)^2-\sqrt x-1=0\implies x-1=\sqrt x\implies (x-1)^2=x\implies x^2-3x+1=0$$

Comment: You may find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026778/if-the-number-x-is-algebraic-then-x2-is-also-algebraic) useful.

Comment: Related reference:  https://mat.iitm.ac.in/home/sryedida/public_html/caimna/transcendental/polynomial%20methods/direct.html.

Answer (score 2):

If $\alpha$ is an algebraic number over $\mathbb{Q}$ then $\alpha^2$ is an algebraic number over $\mathbb{Q}$. Proof: let $p(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $p_{\text{even}}(x)=\frac{p(x)+p(-x)}{2}$, $p_{\text{odd}}(x)=\frac{p(x)-p(-x)}{2}$. We have $p_{\text{even}}(x)=r(x^2)$ and $p_{\text{odd}}(x)=x\cdot s(x^2)$, so
$$ t(x) = r(x)^2-x\cdot s(x)^2 $$
is a polynomial with degree $\leq\deg p$ vanishing at $\alpha^2$, since $p(x)\mid t(x^2)$.

About the golden ratio, this procedure applied to the polynomial $x^2-x-1$ gives that $x^2-3x+1$ is a polynomial vanishing at $\varphi^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$\Phi$ is a root of $f(x)=x^2 - x - 1$. Therefore, $\Phi^2 =\Phi+1$ and so $\Phi^2$ is a root of $f(x-1)=x^2 - 3 x + 1$.

More generally, $\Phi ^n = F_n \Phi + F_{n-1}$, where $F_n$ is the $n$-th [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), and so $\Phi ^n$ is a root of $f\left(\dfrac{x - F_{n-1}}{F_n}\right)=\dfrac{x^2-L_n x +(-1)^n}{F_{n}^2}$, where $L_n$ is the $n$-th [Lucas number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number), $L_n = F_{n-1}+F_{n+1}$. The value of the independent term follows from [Cassini's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities). We can remove the denominator and so $\Phi ^n$ is a root of $x^2-L_n x +(-1)^n$.

This also follows by computing the trace and the determinant of the powers of the matrix
$
\pmatrix{ 0 & 1 \\ 1& 1}
$, which represents the map $ x \mapsto \Phi x$ in $\mathbb Q(\Phi)$:
$$
\pmatrix{ 0 & 1 \\ 1& 1}^n
=
\pmatrix{ F_{n-1} & F_n \\ F_n & F_{n+1}}
$$